# How to have states for hierarchial data using ui-router in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I need to have a url structure in place for hierarchical categories using angularjs ui-router.

Example;

Category tree is like below:

- Root
- -Application 1
- --Category level 1
- ---Category level 2
- ----Category level 3
- -Application 2
- -Application 3

The url ***xyz.com/application-1/category-1*** will display articles in category level 1, similarly ***xyz.com/application-1/category-1/category-2/category-3*** will display articles in category level 3. This can go upto the 4 or 5 levels of categories.

According to my understanding, i will have to define states for each of the category levels and all those states can access the same template and controller. Is there a better, smarter way of implementing these states?

Answer (score 1):

What about use angular ui-router and abstract routing?...something like:

```
app.config([
    "$stateProvider",
    "$urlRouterProvider",
    "$ocLazyLoadProvider",
    "$locationProvider",
    function (
        $stateProvider,
        $urlRouterProvider,
        $ocLazyLoadProvider,
        $locationProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/main");


        $stateProvider

            .state("application1", {

                abstract: true, // <-- MEAN IT?S  A PARENT URL / TEMPLATE
                url: "/index",
                templateUrl: "/app/view/template/common/application1.html"
            })
            .state("application1.category1", { //<-- MEANS IT'S A CHILD OF index FATHER
                url: "/main",
                templateUrl: "/app/view/template/application1/category1.html",

                controller: "HomeController",
                controllerAs: "homeCtrl"


            })
```

So the index routing marked as abastract is the 'father' of multiple child

Comment: Yes.. I have this in place already. Please check Charan Cherry's answer below and my comment on it. That is more closer to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use stateProvider with nested states and views https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

```
$stateProvider.state('/home', {
     url: '/home',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
.state('home.app1', {
     url: '/home/app1',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
.state('home.app1.cat1', {
     url: '/home/app1/cat1',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
.state('home.app1.cat1.cat2', {
     url: '/home/app1/cat1/cat2',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
.state('home.app1.cat1.cat2.cat3', {
     url: '/home/app1/cat1/cat2/cat3',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
.state('home.app2', {
     url: '/home/app2',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
.state('home.app3', {
     url: '/home/app3',
     templateUrl: '',
     controller: ''
})
$routerUrlProvider.otherwise('/home'); // if no path matched
```

I didn't mention named views. you can go through the link and It helps a lot.

But the above makes heavy structuring of states. So, you need to display a relevant info in a single state. For example, if there are three categories, and you want to show in single page then you can define a state like this.

```
.state('home.app1',{
   url: '/home/app1',
   views: {
    "view1": {
      templateUrl: 'cat1.html',
      controller: ''
    },
    "view2": {
      templateUrl: 'cat2.html',
      controller: ''
    },
    "view3": {
      templateUrl: 'cat3.gtml',
      controller: ''
    }
   }
})
```

Or you can have a single parent controller for all the views.

now, in html you will have

```
<div>
  <div ui-view="view1"></div>
  <div ui-view="view2"></div>
  <div ui-view="view3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is how i had thought of doing it. But the problem here is, if we add a new level of category, lets say category 5.. then i would need to add a new state. Was thinking if we can avoid this somehow..

Comment: Yes, you can have views in a single state and can display content. But if you need to show the added category 5 in separate state, you must add another state. Actually, in `app1` state, you can have 3 views and display each category in separate views

Comment: Ok that means i am at a bottleneck and will have to add a state every time a new level of category is added and use the same view and controller as my display will be the same for all levels of categories.